# How to pass "description" parameter with TikTok pixel (ttq.track)?

Tags: ads, facebook-pixel, tiktok

I'm using this documentation for implementation: https://ads.tiktok.com/help/article?aid=10028
but every time when I pass 'description' parameter as string or as string in array, I always end with error:

> The parameter for one or more of your events are invalid. This could impact your dynamic product ads. Go to your source code and update the parameter(s) to the supported format.(description)

In this same documentation, at the bottom is a parameter which isn't included in table and only appear in example: `content_name`

Are there any tips to force `description` to work, or is this completely broken on their side? (TikTok company)

My example code:

```
ttq.track('ViewContent',{
    'content_type': 'product',
    'description' : 'test',
    'content_id':   0,
    'currency':     'PLN',
    'value':        1
  });
```

[image: screen from TikTok Pixel Helper]